# HTML <select> inside PHP using mysql data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to HTML and PHP so sorry for a trivial question. I am trying to create a select statement inside my php where i get values for my options from a mysql database. I managed to do it somehow but in my select options, there is a empty line after each entry for some reason. Here is some example code that have the empty lines. Any ideas what might cause this empty lines to appear ? Thanks.

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT title, year FROM Movie GROUP BY title;" , $db_connection)
    or die(mysql_error());


    for($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs); $i++)
    {

        $count = count($row);

        for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
        {
            $temp_row1 = current($row);
            next($row);
            $temp_row2 = current($row);

            print " <option value=\"$temp_row1 $temp_row2\">$temp_row1 $temp_row2</option> ";
            next($row);
        }
    }


    echo  "</select>";
```

EDIT:

Ok so I ended up doing this, which is a much cleaner code for me but I have 1 more problem. For some reason I cant get the value after I press the submit button on select menu.

```
<?php


    echo "<form action=\"./addCommentsToMovies.php\" method=\"GET\">";
    echo "<select name=\"rating\">";


    $db_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "cs143", "")
    OR die("could not connect to database !!!");

    mysql_select_db("CS143", $db_connection);




    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Movie GROUP BY title;" , $db_connection)
    or die(mysql_error());



    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
        $tmp_movieName = $row[title];
        $tmp_movieYear = $row[year];

        print " <option value=\"$tmp_movieName $tmp_movieYear\">$tmp_movieName $tmp_movieYear</option> ";
    }


    echo  "</select>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"GO\"/>";
    echo "</form>";


    $rating = $_GET[rating];

    echo "Print This: " . $rating;


    mysql_close($db_connection);


?>
```

In other words echo "Print This: " . $rating;
only prints "Print This:"  and $rating variable is empty.

Comment: the first `for` should be a `while`, you dont need 2 loops

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: Use POST method instead of  GET

Comment: Manjeet, I am learning PHP, HTML and MYSQL because one of my courses requires the knowledge, and for some reason they force us to use GET. So I need to know how to do this basic stuff using GET so that I can work on my projects for the course later on.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: tadman unfortunately my professor specifically asked to learn how to use mysql_query for some reason, so I kind of have no choice but to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO

First of all you don't need `current` or `next` function to show your select box,And too much of for loop also.

```
<?php
  $db_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "cs143", "")
OR die("could not connect to database !!!");

mysql_select_db("CS143", $db_connection);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 echo $_POST['rating'];
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="rating"  required>
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
/*Selects all the available shows*/
$sql="SELECT title, year FROM Movie GROUP BY title";
$result_show=mysql_query($sql_show);
while($row_show=mysql_fetch_array($result_show))
{ 
    $value=$row_show['title'].$row_show['year'];   
    $display=$row_show['title'].$row_show['year'];  
   //I can use single variable to this but you need to understand 
    echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$display.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Watch out for dragon :) he is about to vote you down.

Comment: Sanooj I am still getting some empty options once in a few rows. Any clue what might cause this ?

Comment: did you run that query in your db is that perfect?

Comment: Yes I do run it on my DB. Actually I just noticed something strange.

I just pulled the value from one of the empty lines and echoed it and got
something like this for example

13th Warrior>

All empty lines have the movie name and then > after the name, and these ones show up as empty in options. I just checked my DB and there is nothing wrong with these movie names.

Comment: your movie name have `>` this symbol ?

Comment: Ok, I am not sure why but replacing the line

echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$display.'</option>';

with

echo " <option value=\"$value\">$display</option> ";

Fixed the problem, no more empty lines and everything works. Thanks a lot. Now I want to know why the hell the first option produces the empty lines :).

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

<?php 
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT title, year FROM Movie GROUP BY title;" , $db_connection)
    or die(mysql_error());


    for($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs); $i++)
    {

        $count = count($row);

        for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
        {
            $temp_row1 = current($row);
            next($row);
            $temp_row2 = current($row);
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $temp_row1.$temp_row2 ?>"><?php echo $temp_row1.$temp_row2 ?></option>;
   <?php          next($row);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: bro it's common sense question uh can compare code to understad difference i think  no need to explain

Answer (score -1):

create an array that contains all the data, with `mysqli_fetch_array` and use while loop to print data from `$row` data array

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT title, year FROM Movie GROUP BY title;" , $db_connection) or die(mysql_error());

    echo  '<select name="title">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
    {

        echo'<option value="'.$row['title'].'" >'.$row['title'].'</option>';
    }
    echo  "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: why should he try it, eplain

Comment: I'm just trying to solve op's problem, nothing else.

Comment: Dear @Dagon, It's okay.. I understand, but you can give me a warning for explanation instead of down voting... :(

Comment: @LegatusGat , use post method in your form and this to print  rating `if(isset($_POST['rating'])){ echo  $_POST['rating'];}`